# Why docker-compose python no module found for airflow operator

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, airflow

I am working on tests for docker-airflow postgres etl.  My project structure currently looks like this:

```
docker-airflow
|
├── Dockerfile
├── __init__.py
├── dags
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── pandas_etl.py
│   └── tuto.py
├── docker-compose.yml
├── operators
    ├── __init__.py
    └── pandas_etl_over_postgres_operator.py
```

When importing my `pandas_etl_over_postgres_operator.py` into the `pandas_etl.py` dag, I am getting an error that the module is not found.

The pandas_etl.py import code is:

```py
from operators.pandas_etl_over_postgres_operator import PandasETLOverPostgresOperator
```

I have tried the following two alternatives, they also give the same error.

```
from .operators.pandas_etl_over_postgres_operator import PandasETLOverPostgresOperator
```

and

```
from ..operators.pandas_etl_over_postgres_operator import PandasETLOverPostgresOperator
```

The import works fine locally but fails when I build and run using docker-compose.

Comment: Which file is the entry point for running this project?. I believe if you add the absolute path of the root folder into `sys.path`, then you can import the module.

Comment: @Thilak here is a [link](https://github.com/adamdharris/docker-airflow) to the repo.  Do I need to add `ENV PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/airflow` to `Dockerfile`

Comment: @Thilak I tried adding `sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.path[0]), 'operators'))` to `pandas_etl.py` before importing, however still get error `module not found`

Answer (score 0):

Please note that for airflow, by default, the `[core]`>`dags_folder` will have a value of `/usr/local/airflow/dags` meaning that airflow will look for dags at path `/usr/local/airflow/dags`.

As a result, all your dags code should be inside that folder and hence, here are a few things that you need to change for your code to work:

- In `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
- ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags/dags
- ./logs:/usr/local/airflow/dags/logs
- ./operators:/usr/local/airflow/dags/operators
```

- In `pandas_etl.py` file:

```
from operators.pandas_etl_over_postgres_operator import PandasETLOverPostgresOperator
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you need to put your operator inside a plugins directory and mount that into a container. Have a look at the Puckle documentation regarding plugins [here](https://github.com/adamdharris/docker-airflow#custom-airflow-plugins). You can also see and change where your particular airflow instance looks for plugins by checking your configuration file [here](https://github.com/adamdharris/docker-airflow/blob/master/config/airflow.cfg#L120)